# Visual Studio 2022: Resharper - IntelliCode AutoComplete disappearing when typing

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

When using the Resharper extension, I noticed that I can no longer use the IntelliCode auto complete suggestions as they disappear straight after a key press

Is it possible to use this feature in conjunction with Resharper?

**Expected Outcome**

Auto complete suggestion is visible after keypress

**Actual Outcome**

Auto complete suggestion disappears after keypress

[image: Resharper IntelliCode AutoComplete disappearing]

**Version**

Visual Studio 17.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears to be fixed with the release of Visual Studio 17.4.0.

I would recommend anyone having the same issue with versions < 17.4.0 to update by doing the following:

Visual Studio Menu Bar -> Help -> Check For Updates -> Update

Answer (score 0):

Does pressing ctrl+J can show any suggestions?

You can try to disable extensions in Visual Studio. This might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: `Ctrl+J` shows no suggestions - I am using Resharpers Keybind Scheme

Answer (score 0):

We've created a new issue in our bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-490187. Please comment or vote for it to monitor the status of this issue.

Comment: Keep me posted when the fix is available